# Output of Python when virtual environment is activated in Slurm

Tags: python, slurm

I am having troubles finding the output of the sbatch job run in a virtual environment in Slurm. In my python code I save some files using pickle. I included this line in the .sh file that activate the virtual environment

```
source /work/tqdo/qdo/bin/activate
```

Without that line then everything is fine, I can see the output in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a lot of luck following this guide
https://implement.pt/2018/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with-slurm/

Id recommend explicitly specifying the output and error paths within the sbatch script.